# Haskell working with Maybe lists

Tags: list, haskell, option-type

I'm pretty new to haskell and don't get how to work with `Maybe [a]`. Normally I'm coding OOP (VB.NET) and in my free time I want to learn haskell (don't ask why ;) ).

So, what do I want to do? I want to read two files with numerical IDs and find out only the IDs that match in both files. Reading the files is not a big thing, it works wonderfully easy. Now, I get two lists of `Maybe[Ids]` (for a simple example, just think the IDs are Int). So the function I need looks like this

```
playWithMaybe :: (Maybe [a]) -> (Maybe [Int]) -> [Int]
```

Now I want to access list members as I used to like this

```
playWithMaybe (x:xs) (y:ys) = undefined
```

But unfortunately it's not allowed, GHC says for both lists

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe [Int]’ with actual type ‘[t0]’
```

So I played around a little bit but didn't find a way to access list members. Can someone help me out? A little bit of explanation would be a great thing!

Comment: `Maybe [a]` is not a list type, it's a `Maybe` type which may (or may not) contain a list. — It's not clear to me what you're trying to do.

Comment: I try to extract the list [a] out from the Maybe [a] to work with the elements of the list [a].

Comment: Just as list has two basic constructors (`[]` and `x : xs`), `Maybe` has two basic constructors (`Nothing` and `Just x`), which you can pattern match on.

Comment: @sandkasten What do you want to happen if there is no list?

Comment: It is not very clear why you have Maybe at all, and what you are going to do with `Maybe [a]` (there's not much you can do with it). Perhaps more context is needed.

Comment: @melpomene: Just return an list with no elements. Maybe you can give me a example how to match pattern right to get to work with the list?
Compare both list on there vaules and only return values, with are in both lists, for example: <code>[1,2,3] [2,3,4] -> [2,3]

Comment: To convert from `Maybe [a]` to `[a]`, you could use a function like this: `foo Nothing = []; foo (Just xs) = xs`. Or `import Data.Maybe` and just use [`fromMaybe []`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe).

Comment: I will give it a try, unfortunately I'l have to go to work now and just can test it afterwards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To approach your problem from a different direction, I would argue you *don't* want a function that processes two `Maybe [a]`. Bear with me:

Fundamentally, the operation you want to do operates on two lists to give you a new list, eg,

```
yourFunction :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
yourFunction a b = ...
```

That's fine, and you can and should write `yourFunction` as such.  The fact that the data you have is `Maybe [a]` captures some additional, auxiliary information: the operation that created your input lists may have failed.  The next step is to chain together `yourFunction` with the auxiliary information.  This is exactly the purpose of `do` notation, to mix pure operations (like `yourFunction`) with contexts (the fact that the creation of one of your input lists may have failed):

```
playWithMaybe :: Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a]
playWithMaybe maybeA maybeB =
  do a <- maybeA   -- if A is something, get it; otherwise, pass through Nothing
     b <- maybeB   -- if B is something, get it; otherwise, pass through Nothing
     Just (yourFunction a b)  -- both inputs succeeded!  do the operation, and return the result
```

But then it turns out there are other kinds of contexts you might want to work with (a simple one, instead of `Maybe` that just captures "something bad happened", we can use `Either` to capture "something bad happened, and here is a description of what happened).  Looking back at `playWithMaybe`, the "`Maybe`-ness" only shows up in one place, the `Just` in the last line.  It turns out Haskell offers a generic function `pure` to wrap a pure value, like what we get from `yourFunction`, in a minimal context:

```
playWithMaybe' :: Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a]
playWithMaybe' maybeA maybeB =
  do a <- maybeA
     b <- maybeB
     pure (yourFunction a b)
```

But then Haskell also has a generic type to abstract the idea of a context, the Monad.  This lets us make our function even more generic:

```
playWithMonad :: Monad m => m [a] -> m [a] -> m [a]
playWithMonad mA mB =
  do a <- mA
     b <- mB
     pure (yourFunction a b)
```

Now we have something very generic, and it turns out it is so generic, it's already in the standard library!  (This is getting quite subtle, so don't worry if it doesn't all make sense yet.)

```
import Control.Applicative
play :: Monad m => m [a] -> m [a] -> m [a]
play mA mB = liftA2 yourFunction mA mB
```

or even

```
import Control.Applicative
play' :: Monad m => m [a] -> m [a] -> m [a]
play' = liftA2 yourFunction
```

Why did I switch from Monad to Applicative suddenly?  Applicative is similar to Monad, but even more generic, so given the choice, it is generally better to use Applicative if you can (similar to my choice to use `pure` instead of `return` earlier).  For a more complete explanation, I strongly recommend *Learn You a Haskell* (http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters), in particular chapters 11 and 12.  Note- definitely read chapter 11 first!  Monads only makes sense after you have a grasp on Functor and Applicative.

Comment: I realy enjoy reading your answer, its prove a good example and explanation. I think what you mentionend on the end is the goal which my exercise will lead to :) Maybe I stuck to much in OOP, where you will always check if something is nothing and this or that...

Comment: @sandkasten This also checks whether the lists were generated successfully (`Just xs`) or it failed on (at least) one of them (`Nothing`). In Haskell this all happens automatically by using `liftA2`, which keeps code very clear and concise IMO.

Answer (score 5):

In general:

```
yourFunction Nothing Nothing = ...
yourFunction (Just xs) Nothing = 
  case xs of
    [] -> ...
    x':xs' -> ...
-- or separately: 
yourFunction (Just []) Nothing = ... 
yourFunction (Just (x:xs)) Nothing = ...
```

et cetera. Which cases need to be treated separately depends on the specific function. More likely you would combine functions working on `Maybe` with functions working on `[]`.

If you want to "Just return an list with no elements" for `Nothing`, then you can write

```
maybeToList1 :: Maybe [a] -> [a]
maybeToList1 Nothing = []
maybeToList1 (Just xs) = xs
```

A better way to write the same function is `maybeToList1 = maybe [] id` ([docs for `maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:maybe)) or `maybeToList1 = fromMaybe []`, but since you are just starting you may want to come back to this one later.

Comment: Unfortunately I only can check one post as an answer, but I like this one too. It stay close to my logic from OOP, first to check if something contains vaild values before start working with it.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, `[Int]` and `Maybe [Int]` are not the same thing. `Maybe [Int]` includes the extra information that the list may or may not be there. You said that you read the Ids from files. Perhaps, the `Maybe` signifies whether the file existed or not, while the empty list signifies that the file did exist but contained no Ids.

If you want to work with the list, you first need to define what to do if there is no list. You can use this function to extract the list:

```
fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a
```

Maybe you want to treat having no list the same as having an empty list:

```
fromMaybe [] :: Maybe [a] -> [a]
```

Maybe you want to crash the entire program:

```
fromMaybe (error "Missing list") :: Maybe a -> a
```

There is also the more general `maybe` function, which you can use if the default value is not of the same type as what's contained in the `Maybe`:

```
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
```

Both these functions are defined in the module `Data.Maybe`.

You can also just work with the lists as if they existed and worry about their existence later by using `Applicative`. You said you wanted to find the Ids common to both lists. You can do it like this:

```
maybeCommonIds :: Maybe [Int] -> Maybe [Int] -> Maybe [Int]
maybeCommonIds xs ys = intersect <$> xs <*> ys
```

`intersect` is defined in `Data.List`. Using `maybeCommonIds` will result in `Maybe [Int]`. The list contained inside will hold the common ids, but if either of the two lists did not exist, there is not list of common ids. In your case, this might be the same as having no common ids. In that case, you might want to pass the result to `fromMaybe []`, to get back the list.